# Should .htaccess files be allowed in Git for Rails projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Does rails 3.1 have any dependencies on .htaccess files (and thus should be included in the git repo)?

I'm from the PHP CodeIgniter world where .htaccess was required for some of the functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails doesn't care about these server-specific things, so it doesn't care about `.htaccess`.